# Prolog how to pattern match a type with arguments

Tags: prolog

I am trying to learn Prolog, I am quite a beginner. To understand it, I try to write a function. I have a type that is defined in this fashion:

```
a(X,Y,Z).
```

And let's say, my knowledge base is:

```
a(M,2,3) .
a(S,4,7) .
```

Here X is the operation and Y,Z are the numbers that will be subject to this operation. And I have a function f, which will conduct this operation and then if this operation yields to the result with f's second argument, it will return true. Otherwise it will return the result of the operation.

For example,

```
g(M,4)
```

should yield to

```
6.
```

Since M stands for multiplication and 6 is not equal to 4. Let's say S stands for sum operation, then

```
g(S,11)
```

should result in true since 4+7=11.

So, what I tried is:

```
g([],0) .
g(a(M,X,Y),Z, true :- (Z =:= (X*Y) ) ) .
g(a(S,X,Y),Z, true :- (Z =:= (X+Y) ) ) .
g(a(M,X,Y),Z, (X*Y) ) .
g(a(S,X,Y),Z, (X+Y) ) .
```

But when I call
    g(S,11)

I get

```
false.
```

although it should evaluate to 11.

When I call

```
g(S,45)
```

I should get 11, But I still get

```
false.
```

I am very, very beginner so if I am missing some obvious things please don't be too harsh, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code, although syntactically acceptable to Prolog (you are simply asserting compound terms), is completely incorrect in terms of how to define basic predicates. Note, also, that terms like `S` and `M` are variables since they start with a capital letter. Are you using a Prolog manual or tutorial?

Comment: No, I do not. Apparently I should be using. Could you advice any?

Comment: What do you mean by `g(S, 11)` *should evaluate to 11*? A queried Prolog predicate succeeds or fails. It doesn't evaluate to anything.

Comment: There are many good references. Try a search on this site for `[prolog] books` as many have been recommended and explained here already. There's an online Prolog tutorial which is popular, just search for "Learn Prolog Now" in Google and you'll find it. Are you taking a class and do they have materials?

Comment: Not a class related to Prolog, I just found what could be done with Prolog interesting and trying to learn it by my own. I'll look for it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you do need to learn more about Prolog before you can get close to what you are trying to do here. For one thing, Prolog does not have functions, only predicates. This is not just a funny name for the same thing, it is a fundamentally different concept.

Prolog predicates don't evaluate to values in the way that you expect. They either fail or succeed, and in the case of success, they can bind some variables to values. This can seem like "returning" a value in other languages, but it is not the same.

Let's look at this version of your program:

```
a(mul, 2, 3).
a(add, 4, 7).

g(mul, Z) :-
    a(mul, X, Y),
    Z is X * Y.
g(add, Z) :-
    a(add, X, Y),
    Z is X + Y.
```

I can ask it if 11 is a correct result of the addition of the operands stored in the database:

```
?- g(add, 11).
true.
```

I can also ask it what the correct result is, without providing my guess:

```
?- g(add, Result).
Result = 11.
```

But you can *not* get it to "return" the correct solution on a wrong guess:

```
?- g(add, 45).
false.
```

This is because any "returning" of values would happen by binding variables in the query. But this query does not contain any variables! You can never "get" a value out of a query that looks like this.

Whatever your goal is, it *can* be done in Prolog, but you are currently not on the right track. You should first try to gain more understanding of concepts like logical variables and the difference of having a term like `a(mul, X, Y)` appearing as a clause in your program vs. the same term appearing as an argument to a predicate.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

Your posted code has a lot of issues. In particular, it isn't proper syntax for defining Prolog predicates, and it uses variables (starting with capital letter) instead of what I believe are intended as atoms.

For example, your code:

```
g(a(M,X,Y),Z, true :- (Z =:= (X*Y) ) ) .
```

Simply asserts a term that looks like this, written "canonically":

```
g(a(M,X,Y), Z, :-(true, =:=(Z, *(X, Y))).
```

It's a valid Prolog term, but isn't Prolog syntax for asserting a predicate. For a predicate, the top level functor must be `:-` (in general, `head :- body`, or written canonically, `:-(head, body)`). In your code, the top level functor is `g` which has no special meaning to Prolog.

You could just use the operators themselves as the description of the operation rather than defining other atoms to represent those operations. So your knowledge base might look like:

```
a(*, 2, 3).
a(*, 4, 5).
a(+, 2, 4).
a(+, 4, 7).
```

And a query might look like:

```
g(+, 11).
```

Then the predicate would be:

```
g(Operation, Result) :-
    a(Operation, Operand1, Operand2),
    Expression =.. [Operation, Operand1, Operand2] ,
    Result #= Expression.
```

Here, we query for an operation with acceptable operands. Then, we use `=../2` to unify the operation and operands to a Prolog *term* that consists of a functor (the first element of the list) and arguments (the rest of the list). Then we use the CLP(FD) `#=` operation to properly reason over integers, as it provides the most general solution, and which evaluates the expression given by the term in `Expression`. This yields the following results with the above facts:

```
| ?- g(+, 11).

yes
| ?- g(+, R).

R = 6 ? ;

R = 11

(1 ms) yes
| ?- g(Op, 11).

Op = (+)

yes
| ?- g(Op, 6).

Op = (*) ? ;

Op = (+) ? ;

no
```

---

If you really needed a different symbolic representation for operators, you could define an alias mapping:

```
alias(add, +).
alias(mul, *).
```

Your facts would be:

```
a(mul, 2, 3).
a(mul, 4, 5).
a(add, 2, 4).
a(add, 4, 7).
```

Then define:

```
g(Operation, Result) :-
    a(Operation, Operand1, Operand2),
    alias(Operation, Op),
    Expression =.. [Op, Operand1, Operand2] ,
    Result #= Expression.
```